# Get the id of a link when clicked using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, click

I'm new to Javascript, and trying to design a form with elements that are created and deleted by clicks on links without submitting a form.

The script depends on getting the unique id of a clicked button (css and `<a>` link), and calculating the id of the row containing the link, and then deleting the entire `<tr>` element.

For this, I'm trying to get the id of a clicked link. The link and the elements it is embedded in, is itself generated by javascript on clicking another button.

I tried the following:

```
var btnDel=document.createElement("a");
btnDel.id="NS_D"+count;
btnDel.className="btn btn-danger";
btnDel.addEventListener('click', function() 
{            
    alert(e.id);
}, false);
var btnText=document.createElement("span");
btnText.className="btn-label";
btnText.innerHTML="Delete";
btnDel.appendChild(btnText);            
td.appendChild(btnDel);
```

Though the button is generated, I'm not getting an alert as expected. Where can I have gone wrong?

Comment: What does the e reference in your alert statement?

Comment: Ah, I thought e referenced the event object. Apparently what I wanted was `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use `this` rather than `e`:

```
alert(this.id);
```

in your event handler.

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/jx6sE/)

(You also need to get used to running your code with the Console visible - that would have told you that the reason you weren't seeing your `alert` is that `e` doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 2):

In the event handler, `this` refers to the element, so you can do:

```
alert(this.id);
```

To get to the `<tr>` you can go up the tree using `parentNode`:

```
console.log(this.parentNode.parentNode);
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler)